# How to represent C2D message in IoT Plug & Play DTDL definition

Tags: azure, iot, playback, plug

I'd like to know how to represent C2D message and External message on IoT Edge module by IoT Plug & Play DTDL definition.
I thought that a Command with a value of "asynchronous" in commandType property is used as C2D message. But when I check the behavior in IoT Central, such a command is handled as a direct method invocation.
Is it possible to represent C2D message by IoT PnP model? If yes, please let me know how to describe that.
regards,

Answer (score 1):

It is a fully managed service which enable secure bidirectional communication between large no of devices and back end.

- `Simulated Device`: connects to your IoThub and receive cloud-to-device messages.
- `SendCloudToDevice`:  app Sends a cloud to device message to device app with the help of IOT hub.

To receive cloud-to-device messages from the IoT hub.

1. Inside visual studio, in the Simulated Device project add given method to Simulated Device class.

```html
     private static async void ReceiveC2dAsync()
         {
             Console.WriteLine("\nReceiving cloud to device messages from service");
             while (true)
             {
                 Message receivedMessage = await s_deviceClient.ReceiveAsync();
                 if (receivedMessage == null) continue;
        
                 Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                 Console.WriteLine("Received message: {0}", 
                 Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedMessage.GetBytes()));
                 Console.ResetColor();
        
                 await s_deviceClient.CompleteAsync(receivedMessage);
             }
         }
```

2. Add `ReceiveC2dAsync()` in main method before  `console.ReadLine()`.

Comment: Hey @user18935372, has it solved your problem else you can share more details so I can troubleshoot?

Comment: If the posted answer justifies your requirement, you may [mark it as the answer] by clicking the checkmark beside the answer. Doing so can benefit other community members

Comment: Thank you for your response but...
My question is not how to receive C2D messages on IoT Device App with SDK but how to describe C2D message in IoT Plug & Play definition by DTDL.
Any idea for this topic?